# replacing multiple values in data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to reassign multiple different character strings with the same value in a single call. However, the following code only replaces *some* of values in each variable.

---

```
dat <-data.frame(x=c(rep("1=x",4),rep("b",4)),y=c(rep("1=z",4),rep("b",4)))
dat[] <- sapply(dat[], as.character)
dat[dat == c("1=x", "1=y")]<- 1
```

such that I get:

```
dat  
x   y
1   1 1=z
2 1=x 1=z
3   1 1=z
4 1=x 1=z
5   b   b
6   b   b
7   b   b
8   b   b
```

when I want is the following:

```
dat  
x   y
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   1
5   b   b
6   b   b
7   b   b
8   b   b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- mutate_all(dat, funs(replace(., grepl("1=", .), 1)))
```

With Base R:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, grepl("1=", x), 1))
```

**Result:**

```
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
5 b b
6 b b
7 b b
8 b b
```

**Data:**

```
dat <- structure(list(x = c("1=x", "1=x", "1=x", "1=x", "b", "b", "b", 
"b"), y = c("1=z", "1=z", "1=z", "1=z", "b", "b", "b", "b")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Base R option if you want to make an explicit replacement of certain strings would be:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat,function(x) ifelse(x %in% c("1=x", "1=z"), 1, x))
```

Result:

```
  x y
  1 1 1
  2 1 1
  3 1 1
  4 1 1
  5 b b
  6 b b
  7 b b
  8 b b
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(x = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
y = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "b", "b", "b", "b")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```